# How do you "upgrade target for ipad" in the new XCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, upgrade

I have an application targeting the iphone.

Now i want to make it universal for both iphone/ipad.

The first step suggested by all the tutorials i ve read is to "upgrade target for ipad" but i think that this doesnt exist anymore.

So whats the new way to do it? Duplicate and then hit Duplicate and Transition to ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Change to universal]
The image shows the project settings page.
Change the target devices to universal

Comment: i did it and it works perfect on ipad. But why it doesnt create the .xib files for the ipad? I mean obviously it creates them and use them because almost all the view look native , but i cant locate the .nib files on my project. Any idea where they are , so i can alter some things to look native for the ipad ?

Comment: create it from New File>iOS>User interface>Empty and create one

Comment: i mean how will my app run this specific .nib file and not the other? Cause it seems that it runs the iphone .nib and autoresizing them to the ipad. But how do i actually use my own .nib files? Even if i create one it continues to use the old .nib file. Do i programmatically need to specify if it needs to use the iphone .nib or the ipad .nib ?